# How do I install pip in python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7, curl, pip

My end goal is to install the requests module, and the way to do that seems to be with pip. I have looked through the pip install documentation here http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/installing.html

The documentation has offered me no help. It tells me to "securely download get-pyp.py". I have been searching for a way to do this, and so far, everything I have seen recommends the command

curl --silent --show-error --retry 5 https://raw.github.com/pypa/pip/master/contrib/get-pip.py | sudo python2.7

I have been unable to figure out how to use this command. Curl is not a python command. I installed curl for windows and ran this command in windows command line, which worked, but I was unable to proceed from there. Is this intended to be installed with windows command line, or something else? I am lost.

Comment: right-click on get-pip.py link, save as..., then run it as any python script.

Comment: cURL doesn't need to be a Python command. It is a bash executable that pipes the output into your Python. You can easily use `setup tools` to install `pip`. The command above works perfectly here. Install cURL for Windows first, from here; http://curl.haxx.se/download.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can first install easy_install (which is part of set up tools) from the following location

```
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools#windows
```

Right click on the link and save the file ez_setup.py and then run it.

Once that is complete and you have added the scripts to your path variable (C...Python2.7..scripts), you can install pip using

```
easy_install pip
```

Check out this video for more help.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MIHYflJwyLk&feature=youtu.be

Comment: Thank you! This method worked for me. I think I may have added the wrong thing to the path variable, because I was not able to run easy_install from the home directory, but I just navigated to C:/python27/scripts and it seemed to run and install from there.

Answer (score 0):

Download the correct version from here: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pip

And can find more info in this question: [How do I install pip on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-to-install-pip-on-windows)